# How to pull one list out of one list in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have this list L1 `[[a, [b,c]]]` and im trying to extract `[b,c]` into another list. I am using `member([_,L2],L1)` and it doesn't work. This does seem to work if L1 is bigger like for example if L1 was `[[a, [b,c]], [d,[e,f]]].` Should I not be using member to extract an element bc the list is only size 1?

Comment: `?- [[a,L]] = [[a,[b,c]]].
L = [b, c]`

Comment: Yes, it works!  
```?- L1=[[a, [b,c]]], member([_,L2],L1).  L1 = [[a, [b, c]]], L2 = [b, c].```